# Approach for solving Graph Problems during practice

Tags: graph, graph-algorithm

During the practice when I am solving the graph problems I sometimes need to write lot of code ( Edge API, Graph API, Indexed Priority Queue in case of Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm). I don't want to sound lazy but this can become time consuming given the fact that I have written these API already and I know how to implement them. So should I maintain copy of these and just use them in the code whenever required so that it can save me time.
Can you suggest me the approach that has been successful for you?
Will really appreciate any help!

Comment: you can and should do that.

Comment: Thank-you @xashru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advice you to store these APIs somewhere (e.g. IDE, Github) where you have quick access on them and copy them.

Comment: Thank-you so much 